# making a help file for my application

Tags: c#

I'm working on a legacy application, i'm actually rewriting it from scratch in C#.NET.
and it used to give some kind of help to the user using WinHelp but Vista(the system i'm developping on) says it doesn't support WinHelp. so what i'm asking is :

How do I make a similar system from C#.NET ? I want the new feature to be used in Vista, XP and previous Windows versions.

Answer (score 3):

Use CHM files instead of pretty much deprecated WinHelp files. You can use [HTML Help Workshop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en) to create those files.

Comment: CHMs are great, I only recently realized you can open them with 7zip. CHMs are easy, portable and not going to end up depercated in anytime soon.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, Mehrdad.
you're right, it's better for me to use CHMs.

Answer (score 3):

You may try out [Help & Manual](http://www.ec-software.com/). It's a great tool.

Comment: I've used this before to and it's great!

Comment: We have been using Help & Manual for over ten years. It's a great product, you can generate .CHM, .PDF and HTML from the same source. H&M is a GUI tool of course, but also has command-line option for batch processing of repetitive steps. Worth every cent.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to be looking into using the [Microsoft Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) documentation generator nowadays. It is perfectly capable of generating HTML Help v1.0/1.1 files (CHM) or v2.0 (for integration into Visual Studio Help). The actual .NET Framework development team used it (or a variant of it) to create the API documentation for the BCL, so you should have an idea of what it is capable of. I'm not sure on the exact nature of your intended documentation of course, but Sandcastle can be used *both for generating API documentation* and accompanying help pages (guides, tutorials, examples, whitepapers, glossaries, etc.) using its custom MAML (XML-like) markup language, which is essentially what gets used in XML comments in code.

[Here](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) is a basic guide to getting started with Sandcastle, but I suspect you'll just need to play around with it for a bit to understand it. The learning curve isn't particularly steep either, unless you insist on learning it from the command line. The easiest option by far is to use the [Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which is superb tool and does not restrict you at all.

Another useful resource is [this C# XML Documentation guide](http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html#seealso), which shows you how to properly document your API with XML comments that can get converted into CHM documentation and also IntelliSense.

Comment: Sandcastle is great for generating API help. But not much for context sensitive help within an application.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Actually, it does a good job at both API and custom textual documentation. I've used it a fair amount in my experience, and found it easy to do either.

Comment: @Noldorin: I agree it's a powerful tool but it provides so much unneeded power sometimes. Specifically, there are cases in which the application documentation is essentially a set of raw HTML files which you want to bind together. I prefer command line hh.exe in that case.

Comment: I'm reviewing SandCastle.
will tell you about my feelings regarding it later.
thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, I guess it's a matter of personal preference to some extent. Sandcastle is certainly well *capable* of turning MAML or even HTML documents into a help file. We'll just have to see what the asker prefers.

Comment: @Attilah: Ok, let me know if you have any queries. :)